# Convert a list of dictionaries to a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in Python

```
[
{'id':'1', 'name': 'a', 'year': '1990'},
{'id':'2', 'name': 'b', 'year': '1991'},
{'id':'3', 'name': 'c', 'year': '1992'},
{'id':'4', 'name': 'd', 'year': '1993'},
]
```

I want to turn this list into a dictionary of dictionaries with the key being the value of `name`.  Note here different items in the list have different values of `name`.

```
{
'a': {'id':'1', 'year': '1990'},
'b': {'id':'2', 'year': '1990'},
'c': {'id':'3', 'year': '1990'},
'd': {'id':'4', 'year': '1990'}
}
```

What is the best way to achieve this?  Thanks.

This is similar to [Python - create dictionary from list of dictionaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481870/python-create-dictionary-from-list-of-dictionaries), but different.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 13):

You can also achieve this using [Dictionary Comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14507591/python-dictionary-comprehension).

```
data = [
        {'id':'1', 'name': 'a', 'year': '1990'},
        {'id':'2', 'name': 'b', 'year': '1991'},
        {'id':'3', 'name': 'c', 'year': '1992'},
        {'id':'4', 'name': 'd', 'year': '1993'},
       ]

print {each.pop('name'): each for each in data}
```

Results :-

```
{'a': {'year': '1990', 'id': '1'}, 
 'c': {'year': '1992', 'id': '3'}, 
 'b': {'year': '1991', 'id': '2'}, 
 'd': {'year': '1993', 'id': '4'}}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
def to_dict(dicts):
    if not dicts:
        return {}
    out_dict = {}
    for d in dicts:
        out_dict[d.pop('name')] = d
    return out_dict
```

Comment: You don't need the guard clause (`if not dicts: return {}`).  If `dicts` is empty, `return out_dict` will return an empty dictionary anyway.  (Also, thanks for reminding me that dictionaries have a `pop` method.)

Comment: I want to return dict even if `None` is passed as a argument value.

Comment: Gotcha.  Matter of taste to you handle a `None` input, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
z = [
{'id':'1', 'name': 'a', 'year': '1990'},
{'id':'2', 'name': 'b', 'year': '1991'},
{'id':'3', 'name': 'c', 'year': '1992'},
{'id':'4', 'name': 'd', 'year': '1993'},
]
dict_ = {indic['name']:{
        k:indic[k] for k in indic if k != 'name'} for indic in z}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it be created so that no need to specify other keys like `'id':x['id'], 'year':x['year']` ?

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
>>> my_list = [
{'id':'1', 'name': 'a', 'year': '1990'},
{'id':'2', 'name': 'b', 'year': '1991'},
{'id':'3', 'name': 'c', 'year': '1992'},
{'id':'4', 'name': 'd', 'year': '1993'},
]
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for x in my_list:
...     my_dict[x['name']] = dict((key, value) for key,value in x.items() if key!='name')
... 
>>> my_dict
{'a': {'id': '1', 'year': '1990'}, 'c': {'id': '3', 'year': '1992'}, 'b': {'id': '2', 'year': '1991'}, 'd': {'id': '4', 'year': '1993'}}
```